# Comparing Date Formats in Perl

Tags: perl

I want to compare different date formats in Perl like:

```
Date :-20140511062730Z
```

compare with

```
Date :- 11-MAY-2014
```

Please suggest of how can we compare them if both these formats are in one file and need to extract them in different files.

File data is :-

dn: uid=501553930,ou=worker,dc=tfayd,dc=com
modifytimestamp: 20140511062730Z
effectiveenddate: 11-MAY-2014

Here this user have same date format so should go in same_date_logs

dn: uid=501909342,ou=worker,dc=tfayd,dc=com
modifytimestamp: 20140611062730Z
effectiveenddate: 11-MAY-2013

Here this user have different date format so should go in different_date_logs

Compare modifytimestamp with effectiveenddate for each record. File contains 1L records.

Comment: [`Date::Calc`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Date-Calc/Calc.pod).  Also [`DateTime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by comparing the date formats, but this should help you.

Using the [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) module's `strptime` to parse the different date/time formats you can generate consistent objects that can be compared directly.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $t1 = Time::Piece->strptime('20140511062730Z', '%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ');
my $t2 = Time::Piece->strptime('11-MAY-2014', '%d-%b-%Y');

printf "%s is %s than %s\n", $t1, $t1 < $t2 ? 'earlier' : 'later', $t2;
```

**output**

```
Sun May 11 06:27:30 2014 is later than Sun May 11 00:00:00 2014
```

Comment: thanks for the quick update,i have file as :-dn: uid=501553930,ou=worker,dc=tfayd,dc=com
modifytimestamp: 20140511062730Z
effectiveenddate: 11-MAY-2014
dn: uid=501909342,ou=worker,dc=tfayd,dc=com
modifytimestamp: 20140611062730Z
effectiveenddate: 11-MAY-2013
Need to compare these dates and if same dates are there then delete else write it in file.

Comment: @user3643071: Please add the data to your question. Also explain what you mean. It sounds like you want a record deleted if the `modifytimestamp`is the same as the `effectiveenddate`. Is that right?

Comment: dn: uid=501553930,ou=worker,dc=tfayd,dc=com
modifytimestamp: 20140511062730Z
effectiveenddate: 11-MAY-2014
Here this user have same date format so should go in same_date_logs

dn: uid=501909342,ou=worker,dc=tfayd,dc=com
modifytimestamp: 20140611062730Z
effectiveenddate: 11-MAY-2013
Here this user have different date format so should go in different_date_logs

Need to compare these dates and if both have same date then write in one same_date_logs else in different_date_logs.

Comment: My file contains 1L users with this format, and yes if both modifytimestamp & effectiveenddate are same then write it in a file(Same_date_logs), else write it in(Different_date_logs)

Comment: @user3643071: Please stop adding comments and include the data in your *question*. There are two date fields in each record: please explain which one you want to compare.

Comment: compare modifytimestamp with effectiveenddate for each user

Comment: hope you are able to get my question, for each record 2 fields are to be compared i.e modifytimestamp compare with effectiveenddate. since i've file larger than 1L users so have to make it dynamic for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Would this solution meet your needs? Borrowed from **[Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin)** with Time::Piece.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

open my $same, '>', 'same_date_logs' or die $!;
open my $diff, '>', 'diff_date_logs' or die $!;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($modtimestamp) = /modifytimestamp: (\d{8})/;
    my ($effectiveend) = /effectiveenddate: (\d\d-[A-Z]{3}-\d{4})/;

    my $mod_date = Time::Piece->strptime($modtimestamp, '%Y%m%d%');
    my $end_date = Time::Piece->strptime($effectiveend, '%d-%b-%Y');

    if ($mod_date == $end_date) {
        print $same $_;
    }
    else {
        print $diff $_;
    }
}
close $same or die $!;
close $diff or die $!;

__DATA__
dn: uid=501553930,ou=worker,dc=tfayd,dc=com modifytimestamp: 20140511062730Z effectiveenddate: 11-MAY-2014
dn: uid=501909342,ou=worker,dc=tfayd,dc=com modifytimestamp: 20140611062730Z effectiveenddate: 11-MAY-2013
```

Prints to 2 files (below)

```
C:\Old_Data\perlp>type same_date_logs
dn: uid=501553930,ou=worker,dc=tfayd,dc=com modifytimestamp: 20140511062730Z effectiveenddate: 11-MAY-2014

C:\Old_Data\perlp>type diff_date_logs
dn: uid=501909342,ou=worker,dc=tfayd,dc=com modifytimestamp: 20140611062730Z effectiveenddate: 11-MAY-2013
```